# Show message box if query is = to 0

Tags: c#, mysql, messagebox

This query looks for the Stock availability and the label print out looks like..

```
{
   string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
   string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
   string petPrice = string.Empty;
   string available = string.Empty;
   {
      MySqlCommand cd_price = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Price FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_price), cs);
      MySqlCommand cd_available = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Stock FROM Animals WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_stock), cs);

      cs.Open();
      petPrice = Convert.ToString(cd_price.ExecuteScalar());
      available = Convert.ToString(cd_available.ExecuteScalar());
      cs.Close();
   }
   PetPrice.Text = String.Format("Minimum Donation For A {0}  Is £{1}.", selection_price, petPrice);
   Availble.Text = String.Format("{0}'s Avalible {1} In Your Country.", selection_stock, available);
}
```

How can I have a message box pop up if `stock` is = to 0 ?

***UPDATE***

**OK so I will explain what I am trying to do**

I have an `UPDATE` query that will decrement the stock by 1 every time a button is clicked. The query is below:

```
var myquery = string.Format("UPDATE Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie ='{1}'
and Country ='{0}' and Stock >0", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), 
selection_price);
```

Now what I want is if the `stock` is = to 0 a message or alert to pop up saying selection out of stock.

Comment: Updated question to include more code.

Comment: you'll need to read from the database prior to applying the decrement, as the query runs on a completely different scope (DB engine)

Comment: Ok @Leon so run query for this first?

Comment: `string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;` and `string selection_stock = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;` look to be the exact same.  Aren't you overwriting your values here?

Comment: hmm gives a error if I do not have both as I use the two different strings at the bottom but I will look into it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: yes, you can't bubble events from the db directly into your app. you need that data to decide whether to display the message box.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(available == 0)
{
   Messagebox.show("stock is equal to zero");
}
```

not sure if that answers your question

Comment: -1.  Your answer shows little explanation or effort and your code isn't formatted correctly.  It should be `MessageBox.Show("string here.");`.

Comment: I have now redacted my -1 since you, at the least, have edited it.

Comment: Still wrong. Should be `.Show`